# How do I get the AWS Amplify auth configuration programmatically using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am new to Swift so apologies if this is an anti-pattern or bad solution.

For example I have the following in my `amplifyconfiguration.json` which I have imported into my XCode project:

```
{
  ... 

  "auth": {
    "plugins": {
      "awsCognitoAuthPlugin": {
        "UserAgent": "aws-amplify/cli",
        "Version": "0.1.0",
        "IdentityManager": {
        "Default": {}
      },
      "CredentialsProvider": {
        "CognitoIdentity": {
          "Default": {
            "PoolId": "us-east-1:0xx00x00-xxx0-0x00-x000-00000x0x00x0",
            "Region": "us-east-1"
          }
        }
      },
    }

  ...
}
```

And the following in my code:

```
import Amplify

struct MyView: UIViewRepresentable {
  var identityPoolId: String = ??? // -> What do I use here?
}
```

Is there a simple `Amplify.Auth.getIdentityPool()` API ? I can't find anything in the docs? Or should I try to just parse the JSON file somehow? What would be easiest?

It's for a POC I'm doing which needs to create a Signature V4 request:

```
...

AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: 'us-east-1', identityPoolId: identityPoolId)
let task = AWSSignatureV4Signer
  .generateQueryStringForSignatureV4(
   withCredentialProvider: credentialsProvider,
   httpMethod: .GET,
   expireDuration: 60,
   endpoint: endpoint!,
   keyPath: percentEncodedKeyPath,
   requestHeaders: requestHeaders,
   requestParameters: .none,
   signBody: true)
task.waitUntilFinished()

...
```

Comment: Why do you need the identity pool ID? What's the end goal?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary It's for a POC I'm doing to create a Signature V4 request. I'll update the question